# Eigenvalues of $X = \begin{bmatrix} a & x^T \\ x & I_{2 \times 2}\end{bmatrix}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I am having the $3 \times 3$ matrix

$$X = \begin{bmatrix} a & x^T \\ x & I_{2 \times 2}\end{bmatrix} $$ where $a\in \mathbb{R}$, $x\in \mathbb{R}^2$, and I want to study the range of it's eigenvalues. To do so I have started from

$$\det\begin{pmatrix}a -\lambda& x^T\\ x& I_{2\times 2} - \lambda  I_{2\times 2} \end{pmatrix} = \det(a - \lambda) \det\left((1-\lambda)I_{2\times 2} - (a - \lambda)^{-1} x  x^T\right) = 0$$ but the fact that $a \in \mathbb{R}$ makes $(a - \lambda)^{-1}$ impossible when $a = \lambda$.

Are there any alternatives? Can you please explain or provide some directions on how we can study the range of the eigenvalues of $X$?

Comment: Why don't you calculate the characteristic polynomial of $X$ ?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe I did a relevant edit. Please take a look.

Answer (score 4):

Let $Q$ be a $2\times2$ orthogonal matrix such that $Qx=\pmatrix{\|x\|\\ 0}$. Then
$$
\pmatrix{1\\ &Q}X\pmatrix{1\\ &Q}^T=\pmatrix{a&\|x\|&0\\ \|x\|&1&0\\ 0&0&1}.
$$
Therefore the eigenvalues of $X$ are $1$ and $\dfrac{a+1\pm\sqrt{(a-1)^2+4\|x\|^2}}{2}$.

Comment: Got it, we can have $$Q = \begin{bmatrix} x_1 & x_2 \\ x_2 & -x_1\end{bmatrix}$$ with $x_1^2 + x_2^2 = 1$. Then you apply similarity transform.

Comment: I think your transformations fits with this [post](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/1801/gershgorin-circle-theorem-to-estimate-the-eigenvalues/1804#1804?newreg=e3cedb2c98b6429688d2c0cd355a6202) which talks about the range of eigenvalues.

Comment: May I ask if there is a specific name for matrices that possess a structure similar to matrix $X$? I recall coming across such a term before, but unfortunately, I am unable to replicate the search I conducted at that time.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\lambda \neq 1$ : using the [block determinant formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_matrix_determinant),

\begin{align*} \chi_X(\lambda)=\det\begin{pmatrix}a -\lambda& x^T\\ x& I_{2\times 2} - \lambda  I_{2\times 2} \end{pmatrix} &= \left[(a-\lambda) - \dfrac{1}{1-\lambda}x^Tx \right](1- \lambda)^2 \\
& = (1-\lambda)\left[(a-\lambda)(1-\lambda) - x^Tx\right] \\
& = (1-\lambda)\left[\lambda^2 - (a+1)\lambda + a - x^Tx\right] \\
\end{align*}

By continuity of $\chi_X$, this formula is still valid if $\lambda=1$.

So the eigenvalues of $X$ are exactly $1$, and the roots of $\lambda^2 - (a+1)\lambda + a - x^Tx$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you please explain why $\chi_X$ is continuous and how this property makes $\lambda=1$ a valid eigenvalue?

Comment: $\chi_X$ is a polynomial, so it is continuous. The continuity of $\chi_X$ ensures that the formula $\chi_X(\lambda)= (1-\lambda)\left[\lambda^2 - (a+1)\lambda + a - x^Tx\right]$, which is *a priori* valid only for $\lambda \neq 1$, is also valid for $\lambda=1$ (since both sides are continuous functions of $\lambda$).

Answer (score 3):

This is a $3 \times 3$ matrix, maybe using block determinants is an overkill... The matrix is of the form
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix} a & b & c\\b & 1 & 0\\c & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

So, using the third line to develop the determinant, the eigenvalues of $A$ are the solutions of
$$
(1-\lambda)(\lambda^2-(a+1)\lambda + a -b^2-c^2) = 0
$$

So, the eigenvalues are $\lambda = 1$ and $\lambda = \frac{1}{2} \left(a+1 \pm \sqrt{a^2-2 a+4 b^2+4 c^2+1}\right)$. You can also just use Gershgorin's theorem and conclude that all eigenvalues satisfy at least one of the inequalities
$$
|\lambda -a| \leq |b|+|c|, \quad |\lambda-1| \leq |b|, \quad |\lambda-1| \leq |c|.
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there any way to know which inequality $\lambda \neq 1$ satisfies?

Comment: In general, no, it will depend on $a,b,c$. Each of those conditions define what is called a Gershgorin circle (in the complex plane). If the union of $m$ gershgorin circles forms a connected set disjoint from the remaining circles, it will contain exactly $m$ eigenvalues, counted according to their multiplicities. So, if all three circles are disjoint, each will contain exactly one eigenvalue.